# Does Intel HM70 supports SATA 3 (6 GB) ?

Tags: laptop, ssd, sata, chipset

I want to buy a  laptop and change HDD to SSD. And I want to know Does Intel HM70 supports SATA 3 (6 GB) ?

Comment: This is a very localized question, should the question be: "How do I find out what Intel supports regarding their chips and storage?"  It doesn't show what you have done to reasonably find the answer to this and why you could not resolve this question using the regular avenues, such as contacting the storage manufacturer website, the chip manufacturers website, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sjees.

1. Look the specs the the laptop you are going to buy.
2. or google it (on the laptop model)
3. Or google it (on the chipset name)
4. Or just [Go to the Intel site and look up the HM70](http://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/us/en/chipsets/value-chipsets/mobile-chipset-hm70.html). In which case you would find the schematic below.

[image: Intel HM70 chipset diagram from Intels own website]

Comment: yes, I already googled and found this image, thanks :) But here written that this chipset have only ONE SATA 3 port. So it means that HDD uses SATA 3 and _I can_ reuse SATA 3 for SSD? I ask, because I really don't understand which components of laptop can use SATA 3. So may be HDD uses SATA 2 and SATA 3 used by another important component, and I can't install SSD on SATA 3. Thanks

Comment: The diagram shows that the chipset has one SATA-III port and three SATA-II ports (and no eSATA, since Intel disabled that). How the manufacturer of the laptop wires those connections is to the the manufacturer. To be sure you will need to download the manual of the specific laptop you want to buy and read that. Anything else is based on assumptions.

Comment: Also, sorry about nearly exploding. I have seen to many question where it seemed that the OP did not do any research on his own and just tried to use SU as a search engine powered by other people.